# Show data for 4 edittext when read data from 1 file

Tags: android

I have 4 `EditTExt`, i write data to 1 file. But I don't know solution read data to load again for 4 `EditTExt`again?

```
public void onClickLoad(View view) {
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fIn =
                openFileInput("textfile.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new
                InputStreamReader(fIn);

        char[] inputBuffer = new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
        String s = "";

        int charRead;
        while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer))>0)
        {
            //---convert the chars to a String---
            String readString =
                    String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0,
                            charRead);
            s += readString;
            inputBuffer = new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
        }
        //---set the EditText to the text that has been
        //Can I load data for some textbox in here
        //textBox1.setText(s);
        textBox.setText(s);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "File loaded successfully!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try for writing the data into the JSON format.
Which is light weight and provide you ease to read data according to the EditText and if in future your EditTexts are increased/decreased it will be easy for you to add/remove data from file.

lets take sample:

```
    JSONObject dataToFile = new JSONObject();
    dataToFile.put("EditText1","My Data1");
    dataToFile.put("EditText2","My Data2");
    dataToFile.put("EditText3","My Data3");
    dataToFile.put("EditText4","My Data4");

//Convert JSON to String
String dataToBeWritten = dataToFile.toString();

//Code to Write data to file.
```

When you are reading data from file. Read it as a String.

```
String dataReadFromFile = //Code to Read data from file.
JSONObject dataFromFile = new JSONObject(dataReadFromFile); 
String editText1Text = dataFromFile.get("EditText1");
editText1.setText(editText1Text);
.
.
.
//Till you read all the data
```

Comment: Yes, but the requirement is saving data Write/read data to file.